# Unable to use LIKE with GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get rid of duplicate entries from database, so I thought of using GROUP BY but it doesn't seem to work with LIKE. Below is my query.

```
$query = array();
$query[] = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `id` LIKE :id GROUP BY id";

$query = implode(' ', $query);

$statement = self::$connection->prepare($query);
$statement->execute(
    array(
        ':id' => '%'.$id.'%'
    ));
$data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

return $data;
```

Ok, the table's value structure like this:

```
id:   location:
001        testA
002        testA
003        testB
004        testC
005        testB
```

How to get unique location from a table which values like above.

I tried distinct like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT location, id FROM `table_name` WHERE `id` LIKE :id
```

It seems to return unique ids but, I want to get unique location. I did try distinct(location) but the result is just the same as unique id.

Comment: If you only want unique entries, `DISTINCT` might be what you're looking for, not `GROUP BY`

Comment: I tried distinct after where clause, doesn't work

Comment: It's used as `SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM table...`, not after the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: `it doesn't seem to work` - can you clarify it? Because it should work. Why in where clause there's \`id\` and in group clause just id without `?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.trialno, a.location from table_name a join table_name b on(b.trialno>a.trialno and a.location=b.location) group by a.trialno
```

You get all old entries if location is not unique. It works if trialno is an Int.

Best Regards

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT location, id FROM `table_name` WHERE `id` LIKE '%'.$id.'%'
```

instead of

```
SELECT DISTINCT location, id FROM `table_name` WHERE `id` LIKE :id
```